# Traverse matrix diagonally

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I have got a board of **NxM** cells. I want to traverse it diagonally, from Up to Bottom. Another condition is that I just want to print diagonals that have at least 4 cells. I achieved it with a **while and 3 conditionals** but I am looking for a more simple way.

How is the board defined

```
board = []
    for t in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        board.append([EMPTY] * BOARDHEIGHT)
```

Imagine it contains the following...

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0 aa ab ac ad ae af ag
1 ah ai aj ak al am an
2 ao ap aq ar as at au
3 av aw ax ay az ba bb 
4 bc bd be bf bg bh bi 
5 bj bk bl bm bn bo bp
```

How it should be traversed

```
ao aw be bm 
ah ap ax bf bn 
aa ai aq ay bg bo 
...
ad al at bb
```

Comment: What is your matrix? A numpy array?

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention it. I updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert your list to a numpy array :

```
array = np.array(board)
```

Then, simply use [`np.diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html#numpy.diagonal) :

```
min_offset, max_offset = array.shape[0] - 4, array.shape[1] - 4
# To only select the sub-diagonals with more than 4 elements

for k in range(-min_offset, max_offset+1):
  print(array.diagonal(k))
```

---

Example :

```
array = np.arange(35).reshape(5,7)

# array = [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6]
#          [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
#          [14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
#          [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]
#          [28 29 30 31 32 33 34]]
```

Outputs :

```
[ 7 15 23 31]
[ 0  8 16 24 32]
[ 1  9 17 25 33]
[ 2 10 18 26 34]
[ 3 11 19 27]
```

---

If you wish to print the transverse diagonals with the same criteria, simply flip the columns of your array and do as before :

```
array = array[:, ::-1]
```

with `np.arange(35).reshape(5,7)`, this outputs :

```
[13 19 25 31]
[ 6 12 18 24 30]
[ 5 11 17 23 29]
[ 4 10 16 22 28]
[ 3  9 15 21]
```

Comment: I need to work with each element of the diagonal, to give a weight to the diagonal. Then I need to iterate array.diagonal(K) right?

Comment: @LauraGalera Yes

Comment: And in case of wanting to traverse / this diagonal with the exact same criteria, what should be changed? I did it without numpy, with 2 for and 1 conditional

Comment: You mean you want to traverse the outputs array ?

Comment: In that case simply flip the columns of your array by doing `array = array[:, ::-1]`, then apply the same method to `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.diag, e.g. for an index set `I`

```
for i in I:
    numpy.diag(M, i)
```

Also, if |i| <= max(M,N) - 4 then the diagonals have 4 entries.